# how to integrate google calendar in my android application?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate google calendar in my app to add my events to google calendar but i do not know how to integrate. please any one could you help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: please chck my edited solution...it can be helpful for..let me know in case of concern

Comment: Sir my requirement is ,i need to add date and the event to google calendar api , after that i need to get notification from google calendar api . so can i do it with that help ? –

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

Comment: i was followed this  
developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android . but i did not get any results

Comment: In that case post what you tried and what did not work..

Comment: thank  you for response,please let me know how to work with google calendar, actually i need send an event to google calendar. i followed this tutorial ,developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android and Events creation of calendar like what they told in developer console. but i din not get any calendar .and also i am know to work with apis .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Calendar in your app directly, you can use this GitHub Library that offers a lot of customization:

1. [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid)
2. [Android-Week-View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)

---

But if you wish to use Calendar, you should work with these intents:

Try this in your code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

Add permission..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"...>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

---

As for the Google Calendar access, the best way is to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview).

Answer (score 0):

you can use google API
For example, your hiking app could automatically add routes into a user's calendar.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar.